# How to set DefaultBinder ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder in asp.net mvc 4 using autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, modelbinders, defaultmodelbinder

I want to set ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder=new SmartBinder() in asp.net mvc 4 using autofac, what is the right way to do that?

Comment: It appears what you have there will work as-is. Why does Autofac need to be involved?

Answer (score 1):

In your Global.asax.cs;

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new SmartBinder();
    }
```

Autofac is not needed to do that.